# File::exists() works on Tinker but not on the page/server

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to check within my Livewire component whether a Model name given as a property really exists inside the 'App/Models' folder, to prevent the code from breaking down.

When I test with `php artisan tinker` like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
$modelName = 'User';
File::exists('app/models/' . $modelName . '.php');
```

It returns `true`, as it should.

But when I open the page with said component this is always returning `false`.

Is there something preventing it from running on the server, but it doesn't happen on Tinker?
I'm imagining there's some protection because I'm trying to look at the App folder. If it's the case, what would be a good option to check the validity of the Model?

Comment: If this is Laravel 10, it should be `app/Models`, not `app/models`. Capitalization matters on a Linux server, but not on Mac/Windows local development.

Comment: @ceejayoz It's a good point, I'll fix it regardless, but the server I mean in this case is the Local/Windows one with Laragon.

Comment: Perfect @Pippo . Thanks!